# Authorization failure TIdHTTP over HTTPS when password is russian

Tags: delphi, encoding, https, indy, delphi-xe5

I try to test my webservice with the TIdHTTP (Indy 10.6.0 and Delphi XE5) by this code:

```
GIdDefaultTextEncoding := encUTF8;
HTTP.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
Http.Request.UserName := AUser;
Http.Request.Password := APass;
Http.Request.Accept := 'text/javascript';
Http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
Http.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
Http.Request.URL := 'https://sameService';
Http.MaxAuthRetries := 1;
Http.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(HTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
```

"AUser" and "APass" in UTF-8. When "APass" have same Russian chars I can't login.
By "HTTP Analyze" I see:

```
...
Authorization: Basic cDh1c2VyOj8/Pz8/PzEyMw==
```

Decode from Base 64 (base64decode.org) we can see:

```
p8user:??????123
```

Why DefStringEncoding not work ?

Answer (score 3):

`TIdHTTP`'s authentication system has no concept of `TIdIOHandler` or its `DefStringEncoding` property.

Internally, `TIdBasicAuthentication` uses `TIdEncoderMIME.Encode()`, but without specifying any encoding. `TIdEncoder.Encode()` defaults to 8bit encoding, and thus is not affected by `GIdDefaultTextEncoding`.

If you need to send a UTF-8 encoded password with `BASIC` authentication, you will have to encode the UTF-8 data manually and store the resulting octets into a `string`, then the 8bit encoder can process the octets as-is, eg:

```
Http.Request.Password := BytesToStringRaw(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(APass));
```

On the other hand, Indy's `DIGEST` authentication, for instance, uses `TIdHashMessageDigest5.HashStringAsHex()`, and `TIdHash.HashString()` does not default to any specific encoding, it depends on `GIdDefaultTextEncoding`.

So, you have to be careful about how you encode passwords, based on which authentications you use.  To account for the discrepency, what you could try is not encode `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` itself, but instead encode the password inside the `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event instead when `BASIC` authentication is being used, eg:

```
Http.Request.Password := APass;

...

procedure TMyForm.HttpAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Authentication is TIdBasicAuthentication then
  begin
    Authentication.Password := BytesToStringRaw(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(TheDesiredPasswordHere));
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**:

> Internally, `TIdBasicAuthentication` uses `TIdEncoderMIME.Encode()`, but **without specifying any encoding**.

That last part is no longer true. `TIdBasicAuthentication` was updated in 2016 to now pass an encoding to `TIdEncoderMIME.Encode()`. When an HTTP server asks for `BASIC` authentication, `TIdBasicAuthentication` now checks if the server's `WWW-Authenticate` header includes one of the following attributes: `charset`, `accept-charset`, `encoding`, or `enc` (in that order). If one is found, the specified charset is passed to `Encode()`, otherwise `ISO-8859-1` is used (there is a `TODO` in the code to use `UTF-8` if the username or password contain any characters that do not exist in `ISO-8859-1`).

If you want to ensure that UTF-8 is used in `BASIC` authentication, you are better off setting `Request.BasicAuthentication` to `False` and using the `Request.CustomHeaders` to supply your own `Authorization` header, eg:

```
Http.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
Http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(AUser + ':' + APass, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Alternatively, you *might* be able to just get away with updating the protected `TIdBasicAuthentication.FCharset` member inside of the `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event (which is fired after the server's `WWW-Authenticate` header has been parsed), eg:

```
Http.Request.Password := APass;

...

type
  TIdBasicAuthenticationAccess = class(TIdBasicAuthentication)
  end;

procedure TMyForm.HttpAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Authentication is TIdBasicAuthentication then
  begin
    TIdBasicAuthenticationAccess(Authentication).FCharset := 'utf-8';
    Authentication.Password := TheDesiredPasswordHere;
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```